# HttpURLConnection does not work Android Gingerbread, but works fine in JellyBean

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have this funny problem where I am trying to download an XML file using HttpURLConnection. 
The code works fine on android 4.2 but does not work for 2.3.4

Any help will be appreciated

The code is given below.

```
package com.test.testdownloader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        try {
                            downloadtest();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    void downloadtest() throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://someurl/list.xml");
        new DownloadTask().execute(url);

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = urls[0];
                InputStream is = inputStreamForUrl(url);
                String result = getStringFromInputStream(is);
                System.out.println(result);
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    // convert InputStream to String
    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static InputStream inputStreamForUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.connect();
        return urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }

}
```

It works fine in android 4.2 and 4.3, but does throws this error in 2.3.4

```
08-21 11:15:55.634: W/System.err(5719): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
08-21 11:15:55.644: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
08-21 11:15:55.644: W/System.err(5719):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
08-21 11:15:55.654: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
08-21 11:15:55.654: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
08-21 11:15:55.654: W/System.err(5719):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
08-21 11:15:55.664: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
08-21 11:15:55.664: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
08-21 11:15:55.664: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
08-21 11:15:55.674: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
08-21 11:15:55.674: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
08-21 11:15:55.674: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
08-21 11:15:55.684: W/System.err(5719):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
08-21 11:15:55.684: W/System.err(5719):     at com.test.testdownloader.MainActivity.inputStreamForUrl(MainActivity.java:99)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at com.test.testdownloader.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at com.test.testdownloader.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-21 11:15:55.694: W/System.err(5719):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Are you testing on emulators or different devices?

Comment: devices, never tried them on emulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with the proxy settings. The android 4.2 was using the proxy, but the 2.3 didn't have proxy configured on it.

However, if I configure the proxy in the settings > wireless and network > wifi settings > [menu button] > advanced, the application does not pick up the proxy from that location.

If i mention the proxy in the code,

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.server.url", 8080));
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use Volley, here is a very mini sample:

https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/Act_SimpleRequest.java

A [Jar](https://app.box.com/s/h7a8db233ydx0orlwf0y) to Volley.

But I give you a Util, might be helpful:

```
public static class Connector extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object> {
    private static final int DEFAULT_CNN_TIME_OUT = 1000 * 20;
    private static String    USER_AGENT;
    private String           mUrl;
    private byte[]           mBody;

    public Connector( Context _cxt ) {
        super();
        if( TextUtils.isEmpty( USER_AGENT ) ) {
            // Without this, the default provided by API will be like "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; BASE_Lutea_3 Build/IMM76D)" .
            USER_AGENT = new WebView( _cxt ).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Convenient function to execute the connecting task.
     */
    public void submit( String _url ) {
        this.execute( _url );
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground( String... _params ) {
        mUrl = _params[0];
        Object ret = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            synchronized( Connector.class ) {
                InputStream in = null;
                conn = connect( mUrl );
                // if we don't do conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Encoding", "gzip" ), the wrapper GZIPInputStream can be removed.
                onConnectorInputStream( in = new GZIPInputStream( conn.getInputStream() ) );
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
        }
        catch( Exception _e ) {
            ret = _e;
        }
        finally {
            if( conn != null ) {
                conn.disconnect();
                conn = null;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( Object _result ) {
        if( _result instanceof SocketTimeoutException ) {
            onConnectorConnectTimout();
        } else if( _result instanceof ConnectorPostConnectException ) {
            onConnectorError( ((ConnectorPostConnectException) _result).getStatus() );
        } else if( _result instanceof Exception ) {
            onConnectorInvalidConnect( (Exception) _result );
        } else if( _result == null ) {
            onConnectorFinished();
        }
        handleEstablishedConnection();
    }

    /*
     * Internal help and test function.
     */
    private static void handleEstablishedConnection() {
        try {
            Log.v( TAG, "Connection is established." );
            CookieStore cs = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookieStore();
            if( cs != null ) {
                Log.v( TAG, "------------cookies------------" );
                List<Cookie> list = cs.getCookies();
                if( list != null && list.size() > 0 ) {
                    StringBuilder cookieBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for( Cookie c : list ) {
                        cookieBuilder
                                .append( c.getName().trim() )
                                .append( "=>" )
                                .append( c.getValue().trim() )
                                .append( "=>" )
                                .append( c.getDomain() );
                        Log.v( TAG, cookieBuilder.toString() );
                        cookieBuilder.delete( 0, cookieBuilder.length() - 1 );
                    }
                    cookieBuilder = null;
                } else {
                    Log.v( TAG, "Empty cookies." );
                }
                cs = null;
                list = null;
            }
        }
        catch( Exception _e ) {
            Log.e( TAG, "Error in handleEstablishedConnection: " + _e.getMessage() );
        }
        finally {
        }
    }

    private HttpURLConnection connect( String _urlStr ) throws Exception {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            try {
                url = new URL( _urlStr );
            }
            catch( MalformedURLException e ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid url: " + _urlStr );
            }
            conn = preConnect( url );
            doConnect( conn );
            conn = postConnect( conn );
        }
        catch( Exception _e ) {
            throw _e;
        }
        finally {
            url = null;
        }
        return conn;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection preConnect( URL url ) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        // http://www.aswinanand.com/2009/01/httpurlconnectionsetfollowredirects-bug/comment-page-1/#comment-13330
        // see the url to learn more about the problem of redirect
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        conn.setDoOutput( true );// allows body
        mBody = getBody();
        if( hasBody() ) {
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode( mBody.length );
        }
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Connection", "Keep-Alive" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", USER_AGENT );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Encoding", "gzip" );// force server to send in Content-Encoding: gzip .
        String cookies = onCookie();
        if( !TextUtils.isEmpty( cookies ) ) {
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Cookie", onCookie() );
            cookies = null;
        }
        conn.setConnectTimeout( onSetConnectTimeout() );
        return conn;
    }

    /*
     * Convenient function to check the exiting of body.
     */
    private boolean hasBody() {
        return mBody != null && mBody.length > 0;
    }

    private void doConnect( HttpURLConnection conn ) throws Exception {
        OutputStream out; // the outgoing stream
        out = conn.getOutputStream();
        if( hasBody() ) {
            out.write( mBody );
        }
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection postConnect( HttpURLConnection conn ) throws Exception {
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if( status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) {
            throw new ConnectorPostConnectException( status );
        } else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().put( conn.getURL().toURI(), conn.getHeaderFields() );
            return conn;
        }
    }

    private byte[] getBody() {
        byte[] body = null;
        String bodyString = onSetBody();
        if( !TextUtils.isEmpty( bodyString ) ) {
            body = bodyString.getBytes();
        }
        return body;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Overrides methods here
    // ------------------------------------------------

    protected int onSetConnectTimeout() {
        return DEFAULT_CNN_TIME_OUT;
    }

    protected String onCookie() {
        return null;
    }

    protected String onSetBody() {
        return null;
    }

    protected void onConnectorConnectTimout() {
        Log.e( TAG, "Handling connector timeout gracefully." );
    }

    protected void onConnectorError( int _status ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "Handling connector error(responsed) gracefully: " + _status );
    }

    protected void onConnectorInvalidConnect( Exception _e ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "Handling connector invalid connect(crash) gracefully: " + _e.toString() );
    }

    /*
     * Read data here. The function runs in thread. To hook on UI thread use onConnectorFinished()
     */
    protected void onConnectorInputStream( InputStream _in ) {
    }

    /*
     * Last handler for a success connection
     */
    protected void onConnectorFinished() {
    }
}
```